# タグの順番について

Tags: サポート

編集していたときのタグの順番と実際の順番が異なることがあるのですが、
タグの順番はどのように決まっているのでしょうか？
また、タグの順番を自分で指定することはできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自動で並び替えられるため、手動で順番を指定することはできないようです。

- 基本的にはよく使われるタグが左側に並びます
- メタサイトでは、モデレーター専用タグ、必須タグ、その他のタグという順に並びます
- タグの編集を行った時に、上記の並び替え処理が行われます

参考：[Meta.SE での Jeff Atwood 氏の回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77810/286934)